# cannot delete bitmap from external storage

Tags: android, file, bitmap, storage, overwrite

I cannot seem to delete a picture from the local storage. What I want to happen is: delete the old picture, add a new picture with the same name.
When I change the picture name it has no problem loading it as a new one. But when I don't change its name it shows the old picture.
I tried context.deleteFile(filename). file.exists returns false after deletion but the picture is still there.
A solution with overwriting can be helpful.
I also have external storage permissions in the manifest.
Thanks!

The deletion:

```
void deleteOldPicture(String filename, Context context){
    File file = new ImageSaver(context).setFileName(filename).setDirectoryName("images").createFile();
    file.delete();
}
```

Creating the file

```
File createFile() {
    File directory;
    if(external){
        directory = getAlbumStorageDir(directoryName);
    }
    else {
        directory = context.getDir(directoryName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    return new File(directory, fileName);
}

private File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e("ImageSaver", "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

Saving the file:

```
private String saveFileInSD(String name, ImageView image){
    String filename = name+parentId+".png";
    Log.e("Filename is", filename);
    new ImageSaver(getApplicationContext()).setFileName(filename).setDirectoryName("images").save(((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
    return filename;
}
```

Comment: change the directory where you're saving the picture. Use `getExternalCacheDir()` instead, that way the picture will be temporarily saved and deleted automatically when a picture with the same name is taken.

Comment: @007  still the same problem

Comment: I just posted an answer, take a look at it and try to adjust it to your project structure.. hope it helps. (code taken from my project and it works perfectly fine - saving one image with same name and it's automatically deleted when there is a new one-).

Answer (score 0):

add this library to your Gradle, it will help clean up your code a little bit :

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

the do the following to save the picture :

```
//Compress the Bitmap
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

            //save Bitmap to file and get it form preview activity and especially to avoid TransactionTooLargeException
            File imageFile = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "image.png");
            try {
                FileOutputStream imageFileStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                IOUtils.copyLarge(new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()), imageFileStream);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(imageFileStream);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

to get the path of your saved bitmap just use the following method :

```
imageFile.getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess this would work as well, but the problem was elsewhere. I was using glide to load the images, and it did not replace the image in cache. I had to use
Glide.with(context).load(file).apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
               .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)).into(subItemViewHolder.image);

Comment: glad you solved your problem ! please post your fix in an answer and accept it so future readers may benefit from it..